# Ruby was not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I installed RVM on my Ubuntu machine via this tutorial:

http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/

Everything worked and installed without problem until command:

```
rvm install 2.0.0
```

I get error:

```
'ruby' was not found, cannot install rubygems unless ruby is present (Do you have an RVM ruby installed & selected?)
```

`rvm -v` returns:

```
rvm 1.24.5 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you source bashrc? `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Append the output of `rvm info` to your question. Also, notice when that tutorial was written, 2010. Things change quickly in the Ruby and RVM world, so, instead of going to a site that isn't the source of RVM, go to http://rvm.io/rvm/install to find out how to install it. READ the page before doing anything, so you know what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug with RVM, which has already had a fix released.

https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2382

Update your RVM to head and it will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

So that won't answer your question, but maybe will help with correct ruby setup.

Try using `rbenv`: https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv (most of the rubyists I know switched to rbenv from rvm)

You can find many tutorials on the web, but that one looks fine enough: http://www.stehem.net/2012/05/08/how-to-install-ruby-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-12-04.html

If you want to get more information about `rbenv` you will find it on github page, that I already linked.

Hope that helps.